com.ibm.db2.jcc:db2jcc_license_cisuz removed from maven central repository. The IBM Data Server for IDBC and SQLJ license was invalid
In my spring-boot maven project, I am connecting to IBM DB2 database.
I am using the below dependency in my project.
<dependency>
   ‹groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
   ‹artifactId›db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
   <version>3.69.24</version>
</dependency>

My project build was successful till 24th April 2024.
But from April 25th, build started failing with the below error. Looks like the dependency is removed from the maven central repository.
Failed to collect dependencies at com.ibm.db.jcc/db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar:3.69.24: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.ibm.db2.jcc:db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar:3.69.24: 
Could not transfer artifact com.bm.db2.jcc:db2jcc_license_cisuz:pom:3.69.24 from/to central

Please help on the alternative to db2jcc_license_cisuz or how to fix this.

If you are connecting to Db2-for-Z/OS then adjust your depdendency to a supported and currenltly shipped version . You should edit your questions to specify the target Db2-server-platform and Db2-server-versions, so that a recommended version can be suggested. Or just look it up on the Db2 jdbc driver versions webpage.
